# access denied in XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I am using an XMLHttpRequest to open a URL. when I run my application on localhost, it works properly. but when I want to run form my pc it generates access denied error. Is this something because of security settings on the server? what should I change to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is purely http based and works with local host/host address.

Comment: so what I should do to access it from my pc and not localhost?